# Mapping <Ctrl-Ctrl> to ESC in VIM

Tags: vim, tmux

On OS X, I've changed Caps-Lock to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in the Keyboard Modifier settings. It's great, but I'd like to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> (a quick double-tap) to <kbd>ESC</kbd> in **VIM** (my pinky is resisting <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>). Possible?

Already using `au CursorHoldI * stopinsert` and `set ut=2000` to exit `Insert Mode` after two seconds, but some plugins interfere (completion, most often).

*Aside: Could this, if possible, create a conflict with **Tmux**?*

Answer (score 7):

You cannot map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> by itself in Vim at all, let alone <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. It is strictly a modifier key.

Answer (score 4):

As @echristopherson mentioned, Karabiner can do some serious remap wizardry…
Jumping off his suggestion, I found the Karabiner documentation and came up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
    <item>
        <name>Ctrl Freak</name>
        <identifier>private.double_ctrl_to_escape</identifier>
        <autogen>
            __DoublePressModifier__
            KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L,
            KeyCode::ESCAPE
        </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

I have done some quick testing with it, but from first blush, seems to perform without issue on OSX, SUBLIME TEXT, and VIM (within a TMUX session).

Keep in mind:
This is a ***system wide*** solution though.
For me, that's a good thing. I use a 60% keyboard and need to make the most of my real estate.

For a ***VIM specific solution:***
You will need to add that bit. The documentation can be found [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The free program [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook) can do many remapping things of that nature. I don't know specifically about double keypresses, but I know it can be made to treat a single tap of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as <kbd>Esc</kbd>, while treating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> held down for a configurable amount of time)